# How do you extend the jScrollPane for hover events?

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

Following on from the example found [here](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/scroll_to_animate.html)

I want to get the `jScrollPane` to scroll when the mouse is held down. My reason for this is so that I can make my own arrow buttons. I'd like them to be outside the scroll pane on the top and bottom with the same width of the pane.

I know how to get the buttons to work on a `mousehover` and `mousedown` jquery event, however the pane only then scrolls down once. I want to give it a `Y` value, about `20`, and get it to keep checking if mousedown is still true etc.

But nothing I try seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to set up an interval timer which fires repeatedly while the mouse is over your button. You can get some hints on how to do this by looking at how the arrow buttons work in the jScrollPane code:

https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/blob/master/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js#L503

Here is some example code which does the same from outside the plugin:

```
var api = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
$('#hover-down').bind(
    'mouseover',
    function()
    {
        var scrollInterval,
            link = $(this),
            doScroll = function()
            {
                api.scrollByY(5);
            };
        link.bind(
            'mouseout.demo',
            function()
            {
                clearInterval(scrollInterval);
                link.unbind('mouseout.demo');
            }
        );
        doScroll();
        scrollInterval = setInterval(doScroll, 50);
    }
);
```

You can see it working and play around with it in this jsfiddle:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/WzNM4/1/